# Unable to Preview data loaded to HDFS using WebUI

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to view data on HDFS via the WebUI using port 9870. I am able to view the data from the terminal but get the error code as shown below. I am trying to run Hadoop in a full cluster mode (1 master, 2 worker nodes).

[image]

When I use the command below, I get the required results but I want to preview and download the file from the WebUI.

```
hdfs dfs -cat /user/root/input/data.txt
```

Can someone please show me how to solve this problem?
This is my hdfs-site.xml file.

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>  

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hadoop/data/namenode</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property> 

<property>
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property> 
</configuration>
```